# Making a variable global within a package

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

I've searched the forum but can't find anything on this. I have the following line in a file by itself:

```
FormState = new ReactiveState();
```

Other files in the package can't reference FormState. How do I make it package-scoped instead of file-scoped?

Comment: There is not enough code and information in your question to reproduce your issue. In which file do you have this code? Does referencing this variable throw an exception, or is it `undefined`? In which other files is this access done, and are they added to the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the files referencing your global variable are added after the file with the declaration. For example:

```js
api.addFiles('file-with-global-var.js');
api.addFiles('file-using-global-var.js');
```

If these were reversed, you'd probably see an error. Also make sure to check they are both accessible from the same environment. For example:

```js
api.addFiles('file-with-global-var.js', 'client');
api.addFiles('file-using-global-var.js', 'server');
```

would obviously be a problem, as the server code couldn't read a variable declared only on the client.